# Populating XML file data to db in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml, parsing, hpricot

In order to work with some client information I have been parsing a 3MB XML file with hpricot... but hpricot takes quite some time to parse the file on a regular basis.

I am thinking about populating this data to a MySql db (once a week) so that I can work with the data directly on mysql with rails.

The file is basically is an XML Google Contacts File that contains client information: Name, email, notes... but also some contact contain multiple value fields such as addresses, telephones.

Currently when I am parsing the data I generate a Contact class

```
class Contact <
  Struct.new(:name, :email, :telephones, :addresses, :user_address,:notes)
end
```

`telephones` and `addresses` contain an array with the different values.

I guess that if I want to recreate this structure in the mysql database I would need to create three tables: contacts, telephones and addresses...

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :telephones
end

class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

How would you to populate the `Contact class` data to the database tables?
Is there a way to insert the data directly from the XML file to the database tables?

Any advice and guidance will be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First why not give [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) a try and see if its faster ?

Rails thought people best practices and they came to believe that there is a recipe on how one should program for any given problem. Unfortunately this is not the case, for the usual 90% of tasks there is no magic.

So if you have a contact with some addresses and some telephones it's just that.

Here it's how I would do:

Parse the XML file, if it's too big, stream the parsing.
For each contact in it output a hash just like the `params[:contact]` would usually turn out in a controller after a form is submitted, and have the `Contact` model use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
contact = {
  :name => xxx, 
  :user_address => xxx, 
  :notes => xxx
  :addresses_attributes => [
    {:some_attribute => xxx, :some_other_attribute => xxx}
    ...
  ],
  :telephones_attributes => [
    { :some_attribute => xxx, :some_other_attribute => xxx}
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now all that remains is:

```
Contact.create(contact)
```

Comment: wow, thanks for que quick response! I was missing the  accepts_nested_attributes_for (I did not know it existed ;) I will definitely try nokogiri as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Clyfe, I have been trying to play with your solution for a while but, I do not seem to get it working... when trying to create the contact: Contact.create(contact), I get an "ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Telephone(#73632730) expected, got Hash(#69779430)". Is there any special code I should use in the Contact controler?